# Trying to achieve this functionality with useEffect hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I was just playing around with React hooks to get a better understanding of it and ended up to this use case mentioned below.

So what I want is Sample Component to show the uppercase value of *text* on the first render otherwise the exact text value received by it

Now to achieve this, I have to use two useEffect

1. To make the *text* value uppercase for the first render
2. To update the *text* value when prop changes/updates

What I realized using this approach my state (*I think*) would be updated twice, that is, by both the useEffect hooks. Also, I'll have to keep the same sequence of the effect hooks since they run in the sequence and changing the sequence would make first render spit the normal casing of the *text* value

What could be another(better) way to achieve this?

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const upperCase = str => str.toUpperCase();

const Sample = ({ text }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(upperCase(text));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setState("text");
  }, [text]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(upperCase(text));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{state}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("Sample");
  return (
    <div>
      <Sample text={state} />
      {state}
      <input value={state} onChange={e => setState(e.target.value)} />
      <h3>App Component</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to what you're wanting to achieve here? So you want the text to show uppercase in one part of the DOM but "as is" in another part of the DOM?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the better option would be to do this:

```
const Sample = ({ text }) => {
  const ref = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = true;
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{ref.current ? text : text.toUpperCase()}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You will know if this is the first render or not by inspecting the value `ref.current`.

Comment: [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-rosalind-x0bqu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score -1):

just do 1 useEffect depending on text change like this:

```
const Sample = ({ text }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(upperCase(text));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (text !== state) setState(upperCase(text));
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(state)}
      <p>{state}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This solution will unnecessarily execute the render twice.

Comment: yes this true because first render state will be empty and when updated it will run again but we can add if statement to check state and text difference.